# Insert array to mysqldb

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to insert the following array ( from a html form ) but i believe i'm working with this array in a very awful way

The array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => local
        [1] => file
        [2] => a

    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => remote
        [1] => image
        [2] => b
    )
)
```

Actual code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)==true && empty($_POST)==false){ 
$dataa = ($_POST['code_list']);
}
$data = array_chunk($_POST['code_list'],6);

foreach ($data as  $type=>$ba) {
    echo "INSERT INTO table(f1, f2, f3,) values (";
    foreach ($ba as $a) {
        echo "'$a',";
    }
    echo ");<br>";
}
```

?>

current output:

```
INSERT INTO table(f1, f2, f3,) values ('local','file','a',);
INSERT INTO table(f1, f2, f3,) values ('remote','image','b',);
```

What would be a decent way to do it?

EDIT : No need to show how to connect to a database, i just need to deal with the array data.

Comment: if you are adding all items as different row then its the correct way I assume. Only thing u need to take care taking out last extra , from the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments:

- You should switch to PDO or mysqli and use prepared statements with bound variables. Now you have a serious sql injection problem;
- You can combine multiple inserts in one insert statement: `INSERT  ... VALUES ('local','file','a'),('remote','image','b'),(etc.)`.
  You could also prepare your statement once and then execute it multiple times but combining would be more efficient, especially with a growing number of inserts.

A simple (uncomplete and untested...) example in PDO:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table(f1, f2, f3) VALUES ';
$values = array();
$valCount = 1;
foreach ($data as  $type=>$ba) {
  $row = array();
  foreach ($ba as $a) {
     $val = ":value{$valCount}";
     $row[] = $val;
     $values[$val] = $a;
     $valCount++;
  }
  $sql .= '(' . implode(', ', $row) . '),';
}
$sql = rtrim($slq, ',');

// execute the sql statement using PDO
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($values);
```

At the end of the loop and the trim, the sql should look like:

```
INSERT INTO table(f1, f2, f3) VALUES (:value1, :value2, :value3),(:value4, :value5, :value6)
```

And the value array should have the keys of `:value1` - `:value6` with your values.

Comment: Could you give an example how could i work the array to do use it?

Comment: @Thales I have added an example, but it is untested so you would need to check if the sql string and the values array are built correctly.

Comment: I just had to replace some variables but this worked better than i expected! thanks a lot